# Phraseapp: Command not found

Tags: ios, swift, fastlane, phrase

I'm new to using phraseApp and fastlane. I was trying to pull the latest changes in Phraseapp using fastlane. After calling "phraseapp_all" I get an error message `Exit status of command 'cd ../Project/Resources && phraseapp pull' was 127 instead of 0. sh: phraseapp: command not found`.

I tried reinstalling phrase but no luck. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: It looks like you haven't installed the command line tools for `phraseapp`. https://phrase.com/cli/

Comment: I already installed it via HomeBrew. And also tried reinstalling it. But still same. @Fogmeister

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use brew install **phraseApp** instead of **phrase** only.

I thought that phraseApp was just renamed to phrase. They were somewhat different.

Answer (score 1):

Install PhraseApp client using Homebrew:

```
brew tap phrase/brewed
brew install phrase/brewed/phraseapp
```